# Is polling a folder the same as polling envelopes?

Tags: docusignapi, polling

Reading the Docusign API rules and limits (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/rules-and-limits/) they state a restriction of not polling an envelope more than once every 15 minutes. They provide this API call as an example:

`GET /accounts/12345/envelopes/AAA/documents/1`

My script is set to look at two folders:

```
/accounts/12345/folders/AAA
/accounts/12345/folders/BBB
```

Now both these folders may have the same envelope in each. If I'm polling those two folders in my script every 15 minutes, does that violate the Docusign polling rule since each folder may contain the same envelope?

Comment: what are you trying to do? I'm a little confused by "Now both these folders may have the same envelope in each"? why would you poll folders?

Comment: I have a few users who have shared their folders with me. I'm trying to see all their completed envelopes. These completed envelopes do not appear in any of my folders. One way I have am able to get this working is by looking at their inboxes, but there are times when they both have the same completed envelope if they were both involved in the signing.

Comment: why not use a Connect configuration for the account? this will send you notifications about all envelopes. You can then decide how to filter/what to do with the information in your app...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create an effective polling rate of 7.5 minutes by polling each folder once every 15 minutes? Yes, that's against the rules.

But your case sounds like polling every 15 minutes and, in some cases not under your control, an envelope may be polled more often than once per 15 minutes. That's fine.

But use a webhook instead, and we'll all be much happier.

See my [post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhook-listeners-part-4) on using aws (free usage tier) and we have code examples too.

For your use case, investigate [Recipient connect](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/recipient-connect) webhooks since you're not the sender.